# CSS element overlayed over other CSS element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Currently working on small wordpress site, and found one thing that i cant sort myself. I work on mobile version of site, and want to move two elements (title of page and cart icon) a little top of page.

[image]

i Have inserted this css:

```
.woodmart-shopping-cart {
 margin-top:-80px; // Inserted this
}
```

but element seems to be overlayed by other element:

[image]

tryed to put this:

```
.woodmart-shopping-cart {
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
margin-top: -80px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

But seems like no makes any change. Cart element is still overlayed by other element. Some help here?

**EDIT:**

After some directions from above, i set my css like this:

```
.container {
z-index:999;
position:relative;
}
.page-title.color-scheme-light .entry-title {
z-index:0;
margin-top:-60px;
}
.woodmart-cart-design-5 {
z-index:0;
}
```

but now seems like cart icon is not clickable like before, when you click it does nothing.

But dont see any change. Some tips?

Comment: Show us more code or a fiddle

Comment: What does your browser inspect facility show you is setting the styling for the cart and for the element(s) above it?

Answer (score 2):

Try applying `z-index: 1;` on the card element icon and `z-index: 0;` on the other element.

The object with `z-index: 1;` will be in front of the object with `z-index: 0;` but the objects have to be positioned with `position`

Comment: Tryed to insert this:

'.whb-general-header {
z-index:0
}'

and put 

'.woodmart-cart-design-5 {z-index:1;}'

but seems not makes any change. Still behind other element.

Comment: did you set the other element to `z-index: ;` with lower value?

Comment: Yes i set, but no change. Site that i work is https://imperial-supplements.uk/

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see from only pics and no code, I think you are trying to place the shopping cart on top of your navbar div, right? If your navbar has `position:relative`, then .woodmart-shopping-cart's position has to be: `position:absolute`. This way you can easily control your second element how to appear on top of the other.

Comment: Yes exactly. This is the site. https://imperial-supplements.uk/

Comment: Can you please show us some code because we cannot inspect all the page and find the desired divs you want to work on.

Comment: First div i want to work with is :

`.woodmart-cart-design-5` and i inserted to this element: `.woodmart-cart-design-5: { z-index:1; position:apsolute;}`  and on header element `.whb-general-header: {z-index:0; position: relative;}`

Comment: It has to be the opossite, `.woodmart-cart-design-5 { z-index:0; position:relative; }` and  `.whb-general-header{ z-index:999;position:absolute; }` and maybe add top:-55; if you want to place it higher, It should appear on top of .woodmart. Note: z-index- the higher the index, the higher is the priority and the lower the index-the lower the priority. And since you want .whb-general-header to appear on top of -woodmart-cart-design-5, you have to give higher priority to .whb-general-header. I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Yes you are totally clear what you want to tell me, but that code inserted into both elements not makes what i want to do. This is what i see after makes those two correction:

After step 1: https://i.imgur.com/WbRCH26.png
After Step 2: https://i.imgur.com/b3x3Aa7.png

Comment: You kinda twisted your question. You want only your "Home" header to appear a little higher than it is or just the cart icon ? If you want to change the position of "Home" header, try working out with those whb-column row-whb-col left/right/top because there are so many hidden things which are taking your height. But if you want only the cart to appear on the same line as your nav, try putting it as a  <a href ""> in your nav bar and floating it to right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236682/discussion-between-drmtr-and-leotrimr).

Comment: Just the cart icon,

Comment: Check the discussion room.